# JMF broadcasting ability?

Tags: java, applet, jmf, broadcasting

I'm using JMF in making a live stream from a webcam at server to an applet.
That when any client open the applet, he 'll be able to watch live stream from the webcam at the server.

Till now, i'm just able to make a **unicasting streaming at local network only** that i must enter the destination ip @ the transmitting code at server.

i want a way to make the transmitting available to each client access the applet from any **remote** machine.

Thanks in advance,,
Ali Zein

Answer (score 1):

after all of us dominated by 'easy to use' flash, java applet and its versatility has been forgatten. however if you say 'i am a java guy', study hard the jmf book and SO's pages.
there are really helpful answers by the experienced programmers.

a 3. party free option would be MODERATOR-CONFERENCE from http://www.kemottron.com
it has several extra functions including live broadcast from webcam and desktop.

cheers,